# How do you solve invertible matrices?

Tags: matrices

Prove the property: If A is invertible and k does not equal 0 number, then kA is invertible and
(kA)-1(inverse) =(1/k)A-1(inverse)

Can k equal 1 and then solve this?

Comment: To show a matrix is invertible, it's frequently easiest to just find the inverse. Have you tried just checking and seeing whether $\frac{1}{k} A^{-1}$ is in fact an inverse for $kA$?

Comment: It's better for you to show some of your work, this way you learn more about mathematics since you *attempted* to solve it; it's also better for us, to better *pinpoint* where your problem is, also ... to save our closing/down votes

Comment: I have not because I do not know what k is , that is why I asked if I can choose to have k be 1 or does it matter what the k will be ?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: A matrix is invertible if and only if the determinant is not equal to what? Also, what can you say about the determinant of $kA$?

For the second part, try to multiply them :)